# Creating dictionary from list of lists where keys are the lists

Tags: python

I have a list of list:

```
list = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 10], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 11, 10], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 30, 25]]
```

I want to create a dictionary from this list where the keys are the lists and values are 0:

```
dict = {[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 10]: 0, [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 11, 10]: 0, [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 30, 25]: 0}
```

I tried this: `dict = {key: 0 for key in list}`

but I get an error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You cannot have a list as a key...`dict = {tuple(key): 0 for key in list}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use lists as keys because they are changable - so they are unhashable. You can convert your lists to tuples and use them as keys.

`tuples_dict = {tuple(key): 0 for key in lists}`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create a dictionary with lists as keys, as lists are *mutable* objects. One thing you could do is to create a dictionary from `tuples` rather than lists, as they can be hashed, you can check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for more on this, where as stated:

> Unlike sequences, which are indexed by a range of numbers, dictionaries are indexed by keys, which can be any immutable type

---

So one way you could construct a dictionary, is by mapping the lists to `tuples`, and using them as `keys`:

```
l = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 10], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 11, 10], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 30, 25]]

dict.fromkeys(map(tuple, l), 0)

{(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 10): 0,
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 11, 10): 0,
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 30, 25): 0}
```

---

Also check [Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) for a better understanding

Comment: thanks, but in this case, the keys are tuples not list

Comment: You cannot create a dictionary with lists as keys, as they are mutable objects

Comment: Okay, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

List is mutable so cannot be a key in a dictionary. Convert them into a tuple.  Besides, avoid using list as a variable.

```
dict([(tuple(x),0) for x in lst])
```